# How to get ng-model value from directive to controller in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I created a `custom directive` in which I have given `text box` and I want to take that `model` value in my controller.
I tried to find it, but didn't success.

here is my `directive` code

```
app.directive("bhAddCategory", ["$rootScope", "$timeout", "CategoryFactory", "ArticleFactory", "RecentArticleFactory", "focus", function ($rootScope, $timeout, CategoryFactory, ArticleFactory, RecentArticleFactory, focus) {
        return {
            scope: {
                display: '=bhCategoryToggle',
                imageOverflow: '=bhImageOverflow',
                textBoxCss: '@bhTextBoxCss',
                rmText: '=bhRmText'
            },
            replace: true,
            template: '<div>' +
            '<div class="pull-left forDrop"><input type="text" focus-on="focusMe" ng-class="myColonyList" class="effect1" placeholder="Add a colony" data-ng-model="newCategoryName" data-ng-trim="true" ng-keypress="pressEnter($event)"></div>' +
            '<div class="pull-right"><a href=""><img src="/images/greyplus.png" ng-class="{imageoverflow: imageOverflow}" ng-show="loadplus" data-ng-click="addCategory()" alt="add category"><img src="/images/loader.gif" ng-class="{imageoverflow: imageOverflow}" alt="" ng-show="loadgif" class="colonyloder"></a></div >' +
            '</div>',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.loadplus = true;

                scope.pressEnter = function (keyEvent) {
                    if (keyEvent.which === 13)
                        scope.addCategory();
                };

                scope.resetNewCategoryName = function () {
                    if (scope.rmText) {
                        scope.newCategoryName = '';
                    }
                };

                scope.addCategory = function () {
                    scope.display = false;
                    var addNewCat = scope.newCategoryName;
                    commonNotification($rootScope, true, false, '', '');
                    var categoryData = {
                        category_name: addNewCat,
                        category_type: 0
                    };

                    if (addNewCat !== undefined && addNewCat !== '') {
                        scope.loadgif = true;
                        var category_details = CategoryFactory.nameExists(addNewCat);
                        if (!category_details.exist) {
                            CategoryFactory.addAtPostion(categoryData, category_details.mid)
                            .then(function (category) {
                                    scope.loadgif = false;
                                    scope.resetNewCategoryName();
                                    commonNotification($rootScope, false, true, true, category.success);
                                    $timeout(function () {
                                        $rootScope.newStatus = false;
                                    }, 3000);
                                }, function (error) {
                                    commonNotification($rootScope, false, true, true, error.message);
                                    $timeout(function () {
                                        $rootScope.newStatus = false;
                                    }, 3000);
                                });
                        } else {
                            scope.loadgif = false;
                            commonNotification($rootScope, false, true, true, 'Category name already exists!');
                            $timeout(function () {
                                $rootScope.newStatus = false;
                            }, 2000);
                        }
                    } else {
                        commonNotification($rootScope, false, true, true, 'Category name is required!');
                        $timeout(function () {
                            $rootScope.newStatus = false;
                        }, 2000);
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }]);
```

And here is my controller

```
app.controller('bookmarkCtrl', ["$scope", "$http", "$rootScope", "$timeout", "RecentArticleFactory", "CategoryFactory", "ArticleFactory", "focus", "debounce", "userFactory", function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, $timeout, RecentArticleFactory, CategoryFactory, ArticleFactory, focus, debounce, userFactory) {
}]);
```

Can I get any working demo, so that I can understand  and implement in my code

Thanks in Advance

Comment: your controller is empty in your sample.

Comment: Yes, but what code should be written to get my model value, that's issue,
How can I communicate with my controller?

Comment: there are a couple ways, depending on what you are trying to do, which isn't readily apparent here, especially since you don't show the HTML where your directive is consumed.  The easiest way would be to use a two way binding scope element on your directive definition, but you could also use `$emit` or `$broadcast`.

Comment: I think the best thing you could do would be: Read the AngularJS docs, do some tutorials, read the docs again, try to implemented a plnkr, and then: share it here if you are really stuck

Answer (score 0):

Use a parent scope excecution parameter on your directive.This is a scope function which is declared on your parent controller and is invoked from within your directive whenever you want to pass something to your controller.
To accomplish this we declare a scope parameter in our directive with the '&' prefix

See this example which i created for another answer

http://jsfiddle.net/jwd3gywz/26/

JS

```
angular.module('components', []).controller('Composer', function Composer($scope, $http) {


    // adding snippet to composed text
    $scope.composed_text = '';
    $scope.updateCaretPosition=function(pos){
    $scope.caret_position=pos;
        console.log('called'+pos); 
    }
    $scope.$watch('caret_position',function(){
        console.log($scope.caret_position); 
    })

}).directive('caretPosition', function() {
    return {
        scope:{updateCaretPosition:'&'},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('keyup click', function(e){
                var caret_position = element[0].selectionStart;
                scope.updateCaretPosition({pos:caret_position});
                console.log('my current position: ' + caret_position);
            });
        }
    }
});
angular.module('myApp', ['components'])
```

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<body>
    <div ng-controller="Composer">
        <textarea class="form-control composed_text" ng-model="composed_text" update-caret-position="updateCaretPosition(pos)" caret-position=""  rows="20"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```